# (Non-) Convergence of $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n - 1} \exp\left(2i \pi [\frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}]^k\right)$ when $n \to +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, golden-ratio, cesaro-summable

Let be $$\forall n > 0, S_n = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n - 1} \exp(2i\pi u_k),\quad  \forall k \geq 0,  u_k = \left(\dfrac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k$$

I would like to prove or disprove the convergence of $S_n$ as $n \to +\infty$.

What I have tried:

- First, I tried to express $u_k$ as $(\phi^{2k})_k$ with $\phi$ the golden ratio and use $\phi^2 = 1 + \phi$ in the exponential, but with no success.
- Second, I tried to establish lower / upper bounds of $S_n$ or study $S_{2n}, S_{2n + 1}$ with no success.
- I think I could make use of the irrationality of $\phi$ but would prefer to avoid a proof based on equipartition (as this is what I'm proving in the end).
- Also, this problem is whether $(\exp(2i\pi u_k))_k$ is Cesaro-summable.

Comment: Please [make the title take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer, but intuitively, I would expect $u_k$ to behave ergodically mod $1$, in which case the sum would be close to the average of the unit circle, namely $0$. I don't expect there to be anything special about the golden ratio here.

Comment: Did you do some numerical experiments? I expect that the sequence $S_n$ converges to $1$.

Comment: @i707107 Yes, I expect that $S_n$ converges to $0$ as Jair Taylor expect it. An efficient way to compute $S_n$ is to use $\phi^k = F_{k - 1} + F_k \phi$ and it becomes a matter of computing Fibonacci sequences.

Comment: Not $0$, I think it should converge to $1$.

Comment: @i707107 I agree; $S_n \to 1$.

Comment: For further reading, see this: 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $v_k = \left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k$ and $w_k = u_k + v_k$.
The sequence
 $w_k$ satisfy recurrence relation: $$w_{k+2} = 3w_{k+1} - w_k$$
Together with $w_0 = 2, w_1 = 3$, one can conclude $w_k$ is an integer sequence. This leads to

$$\exp(2\pi u_k i) = \exp(2\pi( w_k - v_k )i ) = \exp(-2\pi v_k i)$$
Since $\left|\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right| < 1$, we have 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} v_k = 0 \quad\implies\quad \lim_{k\to\infty} \exp(-2\pi v_k i) = 1\quad\implies\quad \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = 1$$

Comment: What led you to introduce $w_k$? Intuition?

Comment: So, I guess there is something special about $\phi$ in this case.  Am I right in thinking if you replace $(3 + \sqrt{5})/2$ with $(3 + \sqrt{5})/2 + \epsilon$ the sum will converge to $0$ (assuming $\epsilon$ is a small random number)?

Comment: Since $w_k$ are integers, then $e^{i2\pi w_k}=1$.  So, $e^{i2\pi u_k}=e^{-i2\pi v_k}\ne (-1)^{\epsilon_k}e^{-i2\pi i v_k}$.

Comment: @MarkViola ahh, you are right. I'll fix.

Comment: And this makes the limit $1$, not $-1/3$.

Comment: @JairTaylor It is known  $\{\alpha^n\}$ is equidistributed mod $1$ for almost all $\alpha > 1$. One known family of exceptions are something  called [PV number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number). $\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is one of them.

Comment: @achillehui I see, I did not know about PV numbers.  That is very interesting and surprising to me.  Thank you!

Comment: Is't possible to use Stolz-Ces$\mathrm{\grave{a}}$ro at the very beginning ?.

Comment: @FelixMarin to use Stolz-Cesaro, you need $\exp(2\pi u_k i)$ converges to something. Notice $u_k \to \infty$, it is not immediately obvious whether $\exp(2\pi u_k i)$ converges or not.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks. I got it.